# How can I get questions with answers?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, entity-framework-core

I have two models Question and Answer

```
public class Question
    {
        public int QuestionId { get; set; }
        public string QuestionContent { get; set; }
        public List<Answer> Answers { get; set; }

        public int QuizId { get; set; }
        public Quiz Quiz { get; set; }
    }
```

```
public class Answer
    {
        public int AnswerId { get; set; }
        public string AnswerContent { get; set; }
        public bool IsCorrect { get; set; }

        public int QuestionId { get; set; }
        public Question Question { get; set; }

    }
```

I need to get list of Answers. I can get list of Questions in Quiz but I cannot figure out how to get the answers. If there is anything to do with database design, I would also be glad to get some help. Thanks in advance

Comment: I used to get questions like
`uow.Questions.GetAll().Where(x=>x.QuizId == id)`

I haven't actually found any similar issues. I have seen only this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23677003/storing-exam-questions-in-a-database,
but this is not the proper way to store such data in my case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get answers by particular `QuizId` following way:

```
uow.Answers.GetAll().Were(x => x.Question.QuizId == id)
```

Or if you would like to get everything together:

```
uow.Quizes.GetAll().Where(x => x.Id == id).Include(x => x.Questions).ThenInclude(x => x.Answers)
```

Assuming `GetAll()` returns `IQueryable`

Comment: Thanks i will try later, if it works, i will mark your answer as right :)